# How can I show color-coded Python snippets in my Tumblr blog

Tags: tumblr

I have a [Tumblr-managed blog](http://blog.garlicsim.org), on which I post a lot of Python-related posts. How do I make the Python snippets in my posts show color-coded?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have too many, I would say go for [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

All you have to do is to include some javascript, css and then you're done.

Check some [examples](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) and here is the setup:

> 1. Download a distribution
> 2. Include the script and stylesheets in your document (you will need to make sure the css and js file are on your server, and adjust the paths in the script and link tag)
>
>    - `<link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
>    - `<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>`
> 3. Add onload="prettyPrint()" to your document's body tag.
> 4. Modify the stylesheet to get the coloring you prefer

Comment: The only problem I had with this method is that it expect you to mark your `code` tags with a specific `class`, which is not nice if you are using Markdown syntax. Luckily, it's not a problem to do it using JS on page load.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [hilite.me](http://www.hilite.me/)

> [hilite.me](http://www.hilite.me/) converts your code snippets into pretty-printed HTML format, easily embeddable into blog posts, emails and websites.
> Just copy the source code to the left pane, select the language and the color scheme, and click "Highlight!". The HTML from the right pane can now be pasted to your blog or email, no external CSS or Javascript files are required.

Answer (score 8):

I use Github's [gist](http://gist.github.com/) to do this. Paste in and create the gist and you can then embed them in any web page including tumblr.

Comment: There's a problem here, it needs JS so if a user doesn't have it activated, or if a user is a search bot, your code stays invisible.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. @MladenJablanović You can't use the majority of the web without JavaScript nowadays. I think that is not really an issue.

Comment: Can you give more detail on how to do this? I just tried it and gist renders the embed as `script` elements - Tumblr escapes these, even if you use HTML mode. Any ideas?