# How to put code in your blog posts in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to be able to show something like:

```
function foo()
{
    return "bar";
}
```

Is there a plugin?

I installed one called Code Markup, but this doesn't add any code options when I am adding a new post (at least not that I am seeing).

Comment: check this answer here if it's any help http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7107/how-can-i-show-color-coded-python-snippets-in-my-tumblr-blog/7121#7121

Comment: also, check out wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: There's a codex page on this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts

Comment: Even wordpress.com blogs support sourcecode tags now.
http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

Answer (score 1):

No need for a plugin.

All WordPress Setups come with this option available (unless you change the default setup).

Just enclose it as follows:

```
<code>function foo()
{
    return "bar";
}</code>
```

You can find it below.

[image: Where is the code ?]

Answer (score 1):

I use the [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) plugin. It works well, is simple to use, and supports a good variety of languages.

See an [article on my site](http://grantpalin.com/2010/01/10/net-projects-generating-documentation-with-sandcastle/) for example output.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a code written using Ruby.

In my blog post I would do

```
[sourcecode language="ruby"]
def hello
  puts "Hi! This is Rohit here"
end
[/sourcecode]
```

WordPress has this as a default feature. I haven't used any plugin for this.